Why apt remove tries to remove a file that matches the package name pattern?
At Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 is installed VirtualBox 7 and if exists the /home/<username>/deb directory - deb is a custom directory - and there is located the virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb file. If is executed the following command:
sudo apt remove virtualbox*

It fails with the following error message:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb

If is executed the sudo apt remove virtualbox* command in other directory where is empty or exists files that do not match the virtualbox* pattern is possible to remove.
Just as an experiment, if in other directory exists the virtualbox.adoc file and if the sudo apt remove virtualbox* command is executed it fails with the following error message:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package virtualbox.adoc
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'virtualbox.adoc'

Question

Why apt remove tries to remove a file that matches the package name pattern?

I assumed the apt remove command should be able to remove in peace the package installed within the internals paths owned and managed by apt itself. Furthermore through man apt at the install, reinstall, remove, purge (apt-get(8)) section does not appear a note/indication about this behavior

This is more about the behavior of your interactive shell than the behavior of apt - if you want to pass the wildcard to apt instead of allowing the shell to expand it based on local filenames, use quotes e.g. apt remove virtualbox\* or apt remove 'virtualbox*'

@steeldriver thank you, the latter worked, even it works with "" too. Consider to write an answer to market as valid

apt does not try to remove a file that matches a package name but tries to remove a package that has the same name as the file because you told apt to do so by using the wildcard * while issuing the command in a directory which contains files with matching names. Of course, a package with that name does not exist and apt reports that a package with that name cannot be located.

Just in case the sudo apt remove virtualbox virtualbox-* command works (taken from other tutorial). The point is, observe the difference between virtualbox* that needs use either '' or "" and virtualbox-* that does not need use neither '' nor "". Interesting this slight difference

@ManuelJordan Quoting prevents pathname expansion, that makes the difference.
